# PreInsert and PreUpdate Event Listener in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, event-listener

I have used `PreInsertEventListener` and `PreUpdateEventListener` Event Listener to insert created date and updated date in table.
The problem i am facing is that when i save entity in database created date could not be inserted in table same as with insert updated date at the time of update record it will not insert updated date also.

My code sample is show as below :

Listener Class :

```
public class PreInsertListener implements PreInsertEventListener,  
                                          PreUpdateEventListener 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent arg0) {
        City.class.cast(arg0.getEntity()).setCreated_date(new Date());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("Update event......");
        City.class.cast(arg0.getEntity()).setUpdated_date(new Date());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hibernate Connection class :

```
public class HibernateUtil 
{

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static {
        try {
            AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
            config.setListener("pre-insert", new PreInsertListener());
            config.setListener("pre-update", new PreInsertListener());
            sessionFactory = config.configure().buildSessionFactory();;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Entity save and Update method in DAO :

```
public Long saveCity(String cityName)
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    Long cityId = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        City city = new City();
        city.setName(cityName);
        cityId = (Long) session.save(city);
        //session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return cityId;
}

public void updateCity(Long cityId, String cityName)
{
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        City city = (City) session.get(City.class, cityId);
        city.setName(cityName);
        session.update(city);
        //session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

My Test Class :

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CityDAO cityDAO = new CityDAO();

        long cityId1 = cityDAO.saveCity("New York");

        cityDAO.updateCity(cityId1, "Paris");
    }
 }
```

If i used `session.flush()` than it will insert both date created and updated but updated query is executed every time i call flush method. currently i commented code to call `session.flush()` method as show in code.

What is the solution to this problem ?

Comment: @AndreiI it also not work. i have place `session.evict()` in my dao function after commit statement is it right?

Comment: @AndreiI still not get date value in column on insert and update record.

Comment: @Andreil i have added my answer for this and its work for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had created Interceptor extend it with  Hibernate EmptyInterceptor.
Override method `onSave()` which will be Called when you save an object, the object is not save into database yet and `onFlushDirty()` Called when you update an object, the object is not update into database yet.
In this function i have check my method by its name in which i have to set date at the time of created or updated.
Here is sample code of onFlushDirty() method.

```
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity,Serializable id,Object[] currentState, 
                  Object[] previousState,String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) 
{

    if ( entity instanceof City ) {

        for ( int i=0; i < propertyNames.length; i++ ) {
            if ( "lastUpdatedOn".equals( propertyNames[i] ) ) {
                currentState[i] = new Date();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here `lastUpdatedOn` is my method name which set updated date of record.

onSave() method :

```
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state,   
                     String[] propertyNames, Type[] types)   
{
    if ( entity instanceof City) {

        for ( int i=0; i<propertyNames.length; i++ ) {
            if ( "createdOn".equals( propertyNames[i] ) ) {
                state[i] = new Date();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here `createdOn` is method to set created date for record.

Extend your POJO class with this interceptor class.

Comment: I have one question, If Contact has Address and address is modified but not contact. Will get Address **onFlushDirty** method and hence I can modify its date, But I would also like to modify parent (Contact) lastUpdatedOn. Any suggestion ?

Comment: @SantoshGiri this solution is for particular one object. For object in relation you need to call update on parent object separately

Comment: @YagneshAgola riddle me this, when if Contact has set<Address> and I'm adding new address in existing (Loaded Contact) and when I update contact, does it mean both address and contact is dirty or only address is ?

Answer (score 4):

I recently get same problem when I integrate Spring4 and Hibernate5.
This is my BaseEntity class.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Date modifyDate;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }

    public Date getModifyDate() {
        return modifyDate;
    }

    public void setModifyDate(Date modifyDate) {
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;
    }
}
```

First of all, you need to define EntityListener class.

```
public class EntityListener implements PreInsertEventListener, PreUpdateEventListener {

    private static final String CREATE_DATE_PROPERTY = "createDate";

    private static final String MODIFY_DATE_PROPERTY = "modifyDate";

    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event) {

        if (event.getEntity() instanceof BaseEntity){
            //property name of entity
            String[] propertyNames = event.getPersister().getEntityMetamodel().getPropertyNames();
            //property value of entity
            Object[] state = event.getState();
            for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length ; i ++) {
                if (CREATE_DATE_PROPERTY.equals(propertyNames[i]) || MODIFY_DATE_PROPERTY.equals(propertyNames[i])){
                    state[i] = new Date();
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent event) {

        if (event.getEntity() instanceof BaseEntity){
            //property name of entity
            String[] propertyNames = event.getPersister().getEntityMetamodel().getPropertyNames();
            //property value of entity
            Object[] state = event.getState();
            for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length ; i ++) {
                if (MODIFY_DATE_PROPERTY.equals(propertyNames[i])){
                    state[i] = new Date();
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then, you should register entity event listener.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Component
public class EntityEventListenerRegistry {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * EventListenerRegistry:http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#annotations-jpa-entitylisteners
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void registerListeners(){
        EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = ((SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory).getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners(EventType.PRE_INSERT, EntityListener.class);
        eventListenerRegistry.prependListeners(EventType.PRE_UPDATE, EntityListener.class);
    }

}
```

It worked very well, I hope it's helpful for you.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @thewaywewere This link may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602299/jpa-entitylistener-does-not-work-as-expected/

Answer (score 3):

Do like this

```
public class PreInsertListener implements PreInsertEventListener,  
                                          PreUpdateEventListener 
{
    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getEntity() instanceof City){
            City city = (City)arg0.getEntity();
            city.setCreated_date(new Date());               
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEvent arg0) {
         if(arg0.getEntity() instanceof City){
            City city = (City)arg0.getEntity();
            city.setCreated_date(new Date());                
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work. now whole record is not inserted in database.

Comment: I have added my answer pls. by this way it work for me. Thanks.