# How to decode values after getting data from db all the time

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

I want to decode some values each time when we get data and encode when persist new data into DB.

i dont want to use my encoding and decoding logic in Model class.

Can any one suggest me to any interceptor or some other way to solve this?

Comment: AOP would be a good choice.  If using Spring, it comes built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EntityListener` for the same.

where you can use `@PostLoad` annotation for Decoding data and `@PrePersist`, `@PreUpdate` for persisting and updating data.

Example:

### EntityListener

```
@Component
class EntityListener {
    @PrePersist
    public void onPrePersist(Object o) {
        // encode logic
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void onPreUpdate(Object o) {
        // encode logic
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void onPostLoad(Object o) {
        // decode logic
    }
}
```

### Model

```
@Table
@Entity
@EntityListeners({EntityListener.class})
class Model {
  @Id
  @Column(updatable = false)
  @GeneratedValue
  private int id;

  private String password;

  private String username;

}
```

whenever use crud operations always call EntityListener methods according to their annotation.

Comment: If you go the EntityListener route, check out the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44602299/jpa-entitylistener-does-not-work-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

I've posted this before, but it's applicable here:

```
@around(value="execution(* db.entities.package)")
public void cypher(ProceedingJoinPoint call){
   try {
     // encode or decode logic here
     call.proceed();
   } catch (Exception e){
      // handle exception
   }
}
```

Comment: If you've posted this as an answer, and it is truly applicable, then this question is a duplicate of the first one you answered and the correct behavior is to vote to close this question as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: I've posted the code snippet before, which was applicable to another question.