# How to register Entity Event Listeners with Spring and Hibernate 5

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, events, listener

Now, I would like to upgrade my application from Spring Hibernate 3 to 5

Under hibernate 3, I create a POST-COMMIT-INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE event listener like below

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            ....
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            ....
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="post-commit-insert">
                <bean class="xxxx.AuditLogPostInsertEventListener" />
            </entry>
            <entry key="post-commit-update">
                <bean class="xxxx.AuditLogPostUpdateEventListener" />
            </entry>
            <entry key="post-commit-delete">
                <bean class="xxxx.AuditLogPostDeleteEventListener" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now, I try to create the event listener under Hibernate 5 but not success

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            ...
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="post-commit-insert">
                <bean class="xxxx.AuditLogPostInsertEventListener" />
            </entry>
            <entry key="post-commit-update">
                <bean class="xxxx.AuditLogPostUpdateEventListener" />
            </entry>
            <entry key="post-commit-delete">
                <bean class="xxxx.AuditLogPostDeleteEventListener" />
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The follow message was shown

> Invalid property 'eventListeners' of bean class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean]:
> Bean property 'eventListeners' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
> Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?

I tried to follow this stackoverflow but still not success.

[PreInsert and PreUpdate Event Listener in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368551/preinsert-and-preupdate-event-listener-in-hibernate)

I changed the config like below but still not success

```
<bean id="auditInterceptor" class="xxxx.EntityEventListenerRegistry" />

<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            ...
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            ...
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="entityInterceptor" ref="xxxx.EntityEventListenerRegistry" />
</bean>
```

Comment: hk.gov.ehr.server.EntityEventListenerRegistry should implement org.hibernate.Interceptor.
Have this been the case?

Comment: @bungrudi Yes! you are right. Thanks for your help!
Also, what can I do if I want to register the PostInsertEventListener like this stackoverflow?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20368551/preinsert-and-preupdate-event-listener-in-hibernate

Comment: create another question and I'll help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my comment, the interceptor needs to implement *org.hibernate.Interceptor*.

Answer (score 11):

The most portable way of setting the Hibernate entity listeners is via the [`org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-event-listeners/). This way, you can get it working for both `JpaTransactionManager` and `HibernateTransactionManager`.

### Implementing the `Integrator` interface

You need to implement the `Integrator` as follows:

```
public class ReplicationEventListenerIntegrator 
        implements Integrator {
 
    public static final ReplicationEventListenerIntegrator INSTANCE = 
        new ReplicationEventListenerIntegrator();
 
    @Override
    public void integrate(
            Metadata metadata,
            SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
 
        final EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry =
                serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
 
        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(
            EventType.POST_INSERT, 
            ReplicationInsertEventListener.INSTANCE
        );
         
        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(
            EventType.POST_UPDATE, 
            ReplicationUpdateEventListener.INSTANCE
        );
         
        eventListenerRegistry.appendListeners(
            EventType.PRE_DELETE, 
            ReplicationDeleteEventListener.INSTANCE
        );
    }
 
    @Override
    public void disintegrate(
            SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
 
    }
}
```

Via the `eventListenerRegistry`, you can register the event listeners.

### Setting the `hibernate.integrator_provider` configuration property

Once you are done, you need to set up the `hibernate.integrator_provider` configuration property via the **application.properties** file, like this:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integrator_provider=com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.listener.ReplicationEventListenerIntegrator
```

Comment: Thank you! And one hint for Spring Boot 2.0.0: You can use `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` to set up configuration properties - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51522146/3271406

Comment: kudos to @lu_ko I've forked his repo and added above response as an example how to register events in springboot v2 https://github.com/ivarprudnikov/hibernate-properties-customizer-example

Comment: Might be worth noting that the configuration property "hibernate.integrator_provider" accepts class names (FQDNs) starting with Hibernate version 5.4.9 (https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13614). 
For earlier versions, an Integrator Object must be set.

Answer (score 1):

You can register hibernate EventListener using java class also, as i did.

Please check this one. It Could help you.

1) Register EventListener with Integrator.

```
    @Override
   public void integrate(Metadata metadata, SessionFactoryImplementor 
         sessionFactory, SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) 
   {

      EventListenerRegistry eventListenerRegistry = 
            serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

     /* eventListenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.SAVE)
                     .appendListener(new SaveUpdateEventListenerImp());*/

      eventListenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.SAVE_UPDATE)
      .appendListener(new SaveUpdateEventListenerImp());

      eventListenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.LOAD)
                     .appendListener(new LoadEventListenerImp());

      eventListenerRegistry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.REFRESH)
                     .appendListener(new RefreshEventListenerImp());
   }
```

2) We can check LoadEventListener from here. Just Implements LoadEventListener.
     When you load Book entity from DB then  LoadEventListener will call.

```
  public class LoadEventListenerImp implements LoadEventListener {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LoadEventListenerImp.class);

   @Override
   public void onLoad(LoadEvent e, LoadType type) throws HibernateException {
      logger.info("onLoad is called.");
      Object obj = e.getResult();
      if (obj instanceof Book) {
         Book book = (Book) obj;
         logger.info("Book on load event {} " , book);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I tried this and work fine.

```
@Component
public class EntityEventListenerRegistry {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    private AuditLogPostInsertEventListener auditLogPostInsertEventListener;

    @Autowired
    private AuditLogPostUpdateEventListener auditLogPostUpdateEventListener;

    @Autowired
    private AuditLogPostDeleteEventListener auditLogPostDeleteEventListener;

    @PostConstruct
    public void registerListeners() {
        EventListenerRegistry registry = ((SessionFactoryImpl) sessionFactory).getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT).appendListener(auditLogPostInsertEventListener);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE).appendListener(auditLogPostUpdateEventListener);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_DELETE).appendListener(auditLogPostDeleteEventListener);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With spring 5.3.19 and hibernate 5.6.7, it is just a syntax change with respect to the hibernate 3 version.

```html
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        ...
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                ...
                <prop key="hibernate.event.listener.post-insert">xxxx.AuditLogPostInsertEventListener</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.event.listener.post-update">xxxx.AuditLogPostUpdateEventListener</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <!-- jpaPropertyMap adds on top of what has already been defined in jpaProperties above -->
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <!-- This integrates hibernate with the spring container. As such, eg JPA EntityListeners can be managed by spring. -->
                <!-- As we need to inject a bean into the jpaPropertyMap, we cannot use a prop key in the above 'jpaProperties' xml. -->
                <entry key="hibernate.resource.beans.container">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringBeanContainer" />
                </entry>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```